# Pass contents of cell array as individual input arguments to a function in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, arguments, cell-array

I have a cell array in MATLAB, say `A{1}`, `A{2}`, `A{3}`,...., `A{561}`.
I want pass it to a function argument like:

```
horzcat(A{1}, A{2}, ..., A{561})
```

Obviously, it is a lethargic way to write all the cells. What is the shortcut way to do it?

I have already tried `horzcat(A{1}:A{561})` but it is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert your cell array `A` into a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) using `A{:}` and then pass it as a function input argument e.g.

```
horzcat(A{:})
```